Why rubbibg Elasticsearch under kubuntu 22.04 I got out-of-memory error?
After installing Elasticsearch under kubuntu 22.04 I got error :
A process of unit @UNIT has been killed by the Linux kernel out-of-memory

when trying to run it. I see next output :
root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service --now
Synchronizing state of elasticsearch.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable elasticsearch
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/elasticsearch.service → /lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.
Job for elasticsearch.service failed.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xeu elasticsearch.service" for details.
root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# systemctl status elasticsearch
× elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: oom-kill) since Thu 2024-06-13 13:50:38 EEST; 16s ago
Docs: https://www.elastic.co
Process: 14760 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=137)
Main PID: 14760 (code=exited, status=137)
CPU: 10.606s

чер 13 13:50:30 master-at-home systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd-entrypoint[14760]: ERROR: Elasticsearch died while starting up, with exit code 137
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Consumed 10.606s CPU time.


root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# journalctl -xeu elasticsearch.service
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4073 and the job result is failed.
чер 13 11:31:17 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Consumed 13.724s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit elasticsearch.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
-- Boot 258ffd13f68c45df8e9e081104c1ea0f --
чер 13 13:50:30 master-at-home systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4072.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
░░ Subject: A process of elasticsearch.service unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A process of unit @UNIT has been killed by the Linux kernel out-of-memory (OOM)
░░ killer logic. This usually indicates that the system is low on memory and that
░░ memory needed to be freed. A process associated with elasticsearch.service has been determined
░░ as the best process to terminate and has been forcibly terminated by the
░░ kernel.
░░
░░ Note that the memory pressure might or might not have been caused by elasticsearch.service.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd-entrypoint[14760]: ERROR: Elasticsearch died while starting up, with exit code 137
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit elasticsearch.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 137.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit elasticsearch.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'oom-kill'.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4072 and the job result is failed.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Consumed 10.606s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit elasticsearch.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
...skipping...
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4073 and the job result is failed.
чер 13 11:31:17 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Consumed 13.724s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit elasticsearch.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
-- Boot 258ffd13f68c45df8e9e081104c1ea0f --
чер 13 13:50:30 master-at-home systemd[1]: Starting Elasticsearch...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4072.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
░░ Subject: A process of elasticsearch.service unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A process of unit @UNIT has been killed by the Linux kernel out-of-memory (OOM)
░░ killer logic. This usually indicates that the system is low on memory and that
░░ memory needed to be freed. A process associated with elasticsearch.service has been determined
░░ as the best process to terminate and has been forcibly terminated by the
░░ kernel.
░░
░░ Note that the memory pressure might or might not have been caused by elasticsearch.service.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd-entrypoint[14760]: ERROR: Elasticsearch died while starting up, with exit code 137
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=137/n/a
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit elasticsearch.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 137.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit elasticsearch.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'oom-kill'.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit elasticsearch.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 4072 and the job result is failed.
чер 13 13:50:38 master-at-home systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Consumed 10.606s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░
░░ The unit elasticsearch.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
lines 1099-1160/1160 (END)
[1]+  Stopped                 journalctl -xeu elasticsearch.service

I have in my OS :
# uname -a
Linux master-at-home 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# free
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         8040228     4270620     1154312      365340     2615296     3132548
Swap:        2104476     1939072      165404


nloads# dpkg -s     elasticsearch
Package: elasticsearch
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: web
Installed-Size: 1121705
Maintainer: Elasticsearch Team
<info@elastic.co>
Architecture: amd64
Source: elasticsearch
Version: 8.14.1
Depends: bash (>= 4.1), lsb-base (>= 4), libc6, adduser, coreutils (>= 8.4)
Conflicts: elasticsearch-oss
Conffiles:
/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml 5de21e0eabb17661972c3474282d9c9d
/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-plugins.example.yml 7f8a7b373bc214a1ed991c0599481abe
/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options 1e90a6127d75c1821d5ef624ceaef9f8
/etc/elasticsearch/log4j2.properties ebce96582d9f9953c927e4c7f2f0697f
/etc/elasticsearch/role_mapping.yml 611f6a6b8045d3c6ef65e4e4516e5045
/etc/elasticsearch/roles.yml 7abe692d5407592c6eede1767c5f3e18
/etc/elasticsearch/users d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
/etc/elasticsearch/users_roles d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
/etc/default/elasticsearch 1610f26559b2917b10b20b97cd56769f
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch a73199b7edd3c384dfb5fd549e9b97f7 obsolete
Description: Distributed RESTful search engine built for the cloud
Reference documentation can be found at
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html
and the 'Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide' book can be found at
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html
Homepage: https://www.elastic.co/
License: Elastic-License

I check lines in Elasticsearch config file(default content) :
root@master-at-home:/home/master/Downloads# cat  /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: false

That is my home developers notebook and I would not have a lot of data :
Just a bit(several hundreds at most) rows of data which I would use periodically...
Which options have I to use to fix this error ?

Your system is saying that you don't have enough available RAM to run the software. The usual fix is to see what RAM you can free from other uses, and/or to add more RAM to meet your revised needs.
